# Complex integration of the gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis

This equality appears in the proof of Hamburger's theorem in ***The theory of Riemann zeta function*** by Titchmarsh:

$$\int\limits_{2 - i \infty}^{2 + i \infty} \Gamma(s/2) \left( \pi n^2 x \right)^{-s/2} ds = 4 \pi i e^{ -\pi n^2 x}$$

Please explain why this equality holds.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mellin_transform#Cahen%E2%80%93Mellin_integral

Comment: I didn't know about the mellin transform. Thank you metamorphy.